# No need for mutex, race conditions not always bad, do they?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

I'm getting this crazy idea that mutex synchronization can be omitted in some cases when most of us would typically want and would use mutex synchronization.

Ok suppose you have this case:

```
Buffer *buffer = new Buffer(); // Initialized by main thread;

...

// The call to buffer's `accumulateSomeData` method is thread-safe
// and is heavily executed by many workers from different threads simultaneously.
buffer->accumulateSomeData(data); // While the code inside is equivalent to vector->push_back()

...

// All lines of code below are executed by a totally separate timer
// thread that executes once per second until the program is finished.

auto bufferPrev = buffer; // A temporary pointer to previous instance

// Switch buffers, put old one offline
buffer = new Buffer();

// As of this line of code all the threads will switch to new instance 
// of buffer. Which yields that calls to `accumulateSomeData`
// are executed over new buffer instance. Which also means that old 
// instance is kinda taken offline and can be safely operated from a
// timer thread.

bufferPrev->flushToDisk(); // Ok, so we can safely flush
delete bufferPrev;
```

While it's obvious that during `buffer = new Buffer();` there can still be uncompleted operations that add data on previous instance. But since disk operations are slow we get natural kind of barrier.

So how do you estimate the risk of running such code without mutex synchronisation?

---

*Edit*

It's so hard these days to ask a question in SO without getting mugged by couple of angry guys for no reason.

Here is my `correct` in all terms code:

```
#include <cassert>

#include "leveldb/db.h"
#include "leveldb/filter_policy.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/lockfree/stack.hpp>
#include <boost/lockfree/queue.hpp>
#include <boost/uuid/uuid.hpp>            // uuid class
#include <boost/uuid/uuid_io.hpp>         // streaming operators etc.
#include <boost/uuid/uuid_generators.hpp> // generators

#include <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::filesystem;

using boost::mutex;
using boost::thread;

enum FileSystemItemType : char {
    Unknown         = 1,
    File            = 0,
    Directory       = 4,

    FileLink        = 2,
    DirectoryLink   = 6
};

// Structure packing optimizations are used in the code below
// http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/
class FileSystemScanner {
private:
    leveldb::DB *database;

    boost::asio::thread_pool pool;

    leveldb::WriteBatch *batch;

    std::atomic<int> queue_size;
    std::atomic<int> workers_online;
    std::atomic<int> entries_processed;
    std::atomic<int> directories_processed;
    std::atomic<uintmax_t> filesystem_usage;

    boost::lockfree::stack<boost::filesystem::path*, boost::lockfree::fixed_sized<false>> directories_pending;

    void work() {
        workers_online++;

        boost::filesystem::path *item;

        if (directories_pending.pop(item) && item != NULL)
        {            
            queue_size--;

            try {
                boost::filesystem::directory_iterator completed;
                boost::filesystem::directory_iterator iterator(*item);

                while (iterator != completed)
                {
                    bool isFailed = false, isSymLink, isDirectory;

                    boost::filesystem::path path = iterator->path();

                    try {
                        isSymLink = boost::filesystem::is_symlink(path);
                        isDirectory = boost::filesystem::is_directory(path);

                    } catch (const boost::filesystem::filesystem_error& e) {
                        isFailed = true;
                        isSymLink = false;
                        isDirectory = false;
                    }

                    if (!isFailed)
                    {
                        if (!isSymLink) {
                            if (isDirectory) {
                                directories_pending.push(new boost::filesystem::path(path));


                                directories_processed++;

                                boost::asio::post(this->pool, [this]() { this->work(); });

                                queue_size++;
                            } else {
                                filesystem_usage += boost::filesystem::file_size(iterator->path());
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    int result = ++entries_processed;

                    if (result % 10000 == 0) {
                        cout << entries_processed.load() << ", " << directories_processed.load() << ", " << queue_size.load() << ", " << workers_online.load() << endl;
                    }

                    ++iterator;
                }

                delete item;
            } catch (boost::filesystem::filesystem_error &e) {

            }
        }

        workers_online--;
    }

public:
    FileSystemScanner(int threads, leveldb::DB* database):
        pool(threads), queue_size(), workers_online(), entries_processed(), directories_processed(), directories_pending(0), database(database)
    {
    }

    void scan(string path) {
        queue_size++;

        directories_pending.push(new boost::filesystem::path(path));

        boost::asio::post(this->pool, [this]() { this->work(); });
    }

    void join() {
        pool.join();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    leveldb::Options opts;

    opts.create_if_missing = true;
    opts.compression = leveldb::CompressionType::kSnappyCompression;
    opts.filter_policy = leveldb::NewBloomFilterPolicy(10);

    leveldb::DB* db;

    leveldb::DB::Open(opts, "/temporary/projx", &db);

    FileSystemScanner scanner(std::thread::hardware_concurrency(), db);

    scanner.scan("/");
    scanner.join();

    return 0;
}
```

My question is: Can I omit synchronization for `batch` which I'm not using yet? Since it's thread-safe and it should be enough to just switch buffers before actually committing any results to disk?

Comment: How would "running threads" that are accessing `buffer` notified that the instance they are working with changes?

This is a pretty typical double buffer example, but why try avoid mutexes when you know those make the code correct?  You'll say "performance", and I'll ask if you orofiled it.

Comment: All the threads run over one common parent class member function `work`. They all access this parent member variable at every request. If it changes, they start to see the changed member variable instead. As for your question on using mutexes I have the opposite idiomatic question to you @Chad why should I use mutexes if my program will remain correct without them? :) I couldn't translate `orofiled`, what did you mean by that?

Comment: Do you want `std::atomic<Buffer *>` to avoid UB and mutex ?

Comment: *"why should I use mutexes if my program will remain correct without them?"*. Your program is incorrect, even if it seems correct.

Comment: @Jarod42 that 's pseudocode, there's no way it can or it can not be correct in regular sense because the machine that is expected to execute this pseudo code is a human who reads it and provides an answer to the question. And the only way it can be incorrect `[for you]` is if you didn't get the question or otherwise define the term `correct program` :)

Comment: @Jarod42 I've updated my answer with original `correct` code

Comment: reading and writing the pointer `batch` concurrency without synchro makes the program ill formed. Your architecture+compiler might ensure that accessing that pointer is atomic, but it is pedantically UB. `std::atomic<leveldb::WriteBatch*> batch` seems to fix your issue. `std::atomic` is not guaranteed to be lock-free though.

Comment: The problem with trying to live with race conditions because you don't expect them to cause any serious issues is that your expectation relies a lot on how you think the compiler transforms your source code into executable code (i.e. as a simple linear transformation) ... and modern C++ optimizers are anything but simple linear  translators.  In particular, they will happily re-order the !#$* out of your source code and play all kinds of crazy tricks (via the "as-if" rule) in order to squeeze out more performance, and these tricks will likely invalidate many of your assumptions about safety.

Comment: My comment above is too old to edit, "orofiled" was meant to say _profiled_.

Comment: And looking at this code, I'm not sure the performance penalty would even be measurable given that you're scanning the disk

Comment: @Chad I think you are right, the performance penalty should be neglectable, but to me it seemed as an interesting case to hit a head over...

Answer (score 5):

You have a serious misunderstanding. You think that when you have a race condition, there are some specific list of things that can happen. This is not true. A race condition can cause any kind of failure, including crashes. So absolutely, definitely not. You absolutely cannot do this.

That said, even with this misunderstanding, this is still a disaster.

Consider:

```
buffer = new Buffer();
```

Suppose this is implemented by first allocating memory, then setting `buffer` to point to that memory, and then calling the constructor. Other threads may operate on the unconstructed buffer. boom.

Now, you can fix this. But it's just one the many ways I can imagine this screwing up. And it can screw up in ways that we're not clever enough to imagine. So, for all that is holy, do not even think of doing this ever again.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to say. First mem is allocated, constructor called and then assign operator takes place. There's no room for synchronization in this notation. The same as in my example. There is just no room for something to break because `Buffer` fully thread-safe like any other operation. So, specifically what can happen if we're replacing one instance of thread-safe object by another instance of thread-safe object. There is not much that can break in this case. We may write to wrong `buffer` though but buffer itself won't break.

Comment: @Lu4 There is no guarantee that the constructor is called before the new value is stored in `buffer`. Those two operations take place inside a single statement with no barrier of any kind between them. The CPU or the compiler could reorder the writes if it wanted to. But, again, it doesn't matter -- you don't have to think of a specific way it can fail.